# Why intellesense for file path and installed npm package is not showing in vs code until I press Ctrl + space for typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, filepath, node-modules

intellisense before I press ctrl + space: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVVaO.png)
intellisense after I press ctrl + space: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4y17.png)

I upgraded to vs code version 1.11.0 and opened my project. When I try to use import statement in the code, code completion is not working for installed node modules until  I press ctr + space. But previously (before upgrade) when I start type the node module name in (import {foo} from 'fo') I see suggestions. for foo file but now (after upgrade) it is not working.

Comment: From what I know the only way to get path intellisense in VS code is via the Path Intellisense extension. And it seems to be working fine with the latest version of VS code. Do you have it installed?

Comment: no but before it used to work without any extension. last night it worked for me. But now I updated as the update prompted. Now its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing strings: true in editor.quickSuggestions which is set as false after upgrade to vscode version 1.11.0. You can find these options by going to file > preferences > settings. Then settings.json will open. Then search for editor.quickSuggestions and click on edit icon then set strings to true.

`"editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": true,
        "comments": false,
        "strings": true
    }`